# How can I achieve this design using API data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gridview

How can I achieve this design using API data in flutter? I just need the first row to show it like this.

[[image: image for reference]

I used flutter_staggered_grid_view package to show images like this..

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        primary: false,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        itemCount: postModal.follower.length,
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
            StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 2 : 3),
        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,

        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container();
        },
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **Expanded** widgets leveraging their flex capabilities to achieve something like this:

[image]

They will be behave in an flexible way as you stretch them; and you can use the child **Container** widgets and set their **DecorationImage** property to set images as background images.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: Column(children: [
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Expanded(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                    Expanded(child: Column(children: [
                      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.yellow)),
                      Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.brown)),
                    ]))
                  ])),
              Expanded(
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
                    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.purple)),
                    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.pink))
              ]))
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: I Fetch data from the API so how can I do this in list widget? Thanks for your suggestion, but this thing is a static thing.

Comment: Your question dealt with the design aspect and that's what the answer was. Now, if you want to accomplish this by pulling data from the API you first need to know which information goes where; for example, you're pulling data for 6 users and you'll show their data on each of the regions; I'd pull the data from the API and assign an index to each of the regions so as to feed the corresponding information into them. This is best that you ask in a separate question as now you're dealing with fetching API data and not a design question as the original stated question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i think i have given the wrong title and i will change my title.